# Restrict access to Azure KeyVault using Fluent

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-fluent-api

I need to restrict access to the Key Vault at the time it is created. I am creating through the Fluent sdk, where I can create the KeyVault and define Tags and Resource Group.

Note: with powershell I can perform the operation using the command: **Add-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule** but using Fluent I cannot

here how i create the KeyVault:

```
        var azureClient = await GetAzureClientWithSubscription();

        var rVault = await azureClient.Vaults
            .Define(kvName)
            .WithRegion(Region.BrazilSouth)
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(kvRG)
            .DefineAccessPolicy()
            .ForObjectId(_settings.ObjectId)
            .AllowSecretPermissions(SecretPermissions.Get)
            .AllowSecretPermissions(SecretPermissions.List)
            .AllowSecretPermissions(SecretPermissions.Set)
            .Attach()
            .WithTags(tags)
            .CreateAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been reported to the SDK team, you can see [the issue here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/720). though it is not so elegant, you can call [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/update) to set `networkAcls` after the key vault is created.

Or just create a key vault by [key vault ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2019-09-01/vaults?tabs=json) by [fluent SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-dotnet-deploy-using-arm-template-with-progress/blob/master/Program.cs).

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank you a lot, your tips gave me a north, as the process is already creating the resource correctly, I will go by the REST API to do it.

Comment: @GustavoNogueira,glad to know it is helpful :)